# ¿Por qué este codigo solo imprime hasta el 5?

Tags: python, fibonacci

Estoy intentando sacar los primeros 100 números primos de la serie de Fibonacci, pero el ciclo no avanza más allá el 5.

```
a = 0
b = 1
contador = 0
for i in range (10000):
  c = a + b
  a = b
  b = c
  if b > 1:
    for k in range(2,b):
      resto = b%i
      if resto == 0:
        contador += 1
    if contador == 0:
      print (b)
```

Comment: Eso pasa por que el contador nunca cambia su valor y siempre es 0 pues el resto nunca da 0

Comment: Entonces, ¿Como soluciono ese problema?

Comment: que es lo que haces con la variable contador?

Comment: Verifico  si el residuo de la división entre los distintos números i hasta b es mayor que cero. Si es mayor que cero, significa que el número b no es primo.

Comment: en ese caso no tendrias que sumarle +1 ya que eso ira aumentando primero sera 1 luego 2 luego 3 y asi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas: generar la serie de Fibonacci y chequear si un número es primo. Si tenemos dos problemas, hagamos dos funciones.

La primera función nos dice si un número es primo o no:

```
def es_primo(n: int):
    for i in range(2, n // 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Es simple: probamos a dividir el número por todos los enteros previos.

Para generar la serie de Fibonacci usaremos un *generador*. Un *generador* es una rutina que usa `yield` en lugar de `return`, y la gracia es que no pierde su estado, sino sigue ejecutando.

La función recibe la cantidad de valores a generar:

```
def fibonacci(limite: int):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    yield a
    yield b
    for i in range(2, limite):
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c
        yield c
```

Esta función primero devuelve con `yield` los dos primeros valores de la serie, y luego va generando el resto uno por uno.

**Demo**

Como `fibonacci` es un *generador*, puedo usarlo como si fuera una lista, extrayendo sus valores en un ciclo `for`

```
for i in fibonacci(10):
    if es_primo(i) and i > 2:
        print(f"{i} es primo")
    else:
        print(i)
```

produce:

```
1
2
3 es primo
5 es primo
8
13 es primo
21
34
55
89 es primo
```

Comment: Hola Moe; ¿qué significa que las variables que reciben las funciones sean de tipo n: int? Es que soy nuevo a pyhon.

Comment: El ": int" declara que se espera una variable de tipo entero.